# write permission for group is not inheriting in hadoop using default acl

Tags: hadoop, acl

created sale directory under / in hadoop (hdfs)

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /sale

It got 755(rwxr-xr-x) permission as below

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /

drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs supergroup          0 2015-04-11 18:12 /sale

Now we are trying to set default acl, so that further directories created in sale directory inherit the acl permissions set on sale directory

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -setfacl  -m default:user::rwx,default:group::rwx,default:other::--- /sale

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /

drwxr-xr-x+  - hdfs supergroup          0 2015-04-11 18:12 /sale

plus sign + denotes that default acl has been set on directory

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -getfacl /sale

## file: /sale

## owner: hdfs

## group: supergroup

user::rwx

group::r-x

other::r-x

default:user::rwx

default:group::rwx

default:other::---

Now we are creating a directory under sale to check if the permission are getting inherited as set by setfacl command, but we are seeing that instead of 770(rwxrwx---) permission its getting set as 750(rwxr-x---).
Means we are not able to set write permission on group level in hadoop

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /sale/dir1

[hdfs@vm1 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /sale/

drwxr-x---+  - hdfs supergroup          0 2015-04-11 18:19 /sale/dir1

The above scenario(default acl) is working fine on linux box.
Is there any way to enable same on hadoop/hdfs ?
We are using Cloudera Hadoop 5.2, Is there any configuration parameter we are missing to do this in Hadoop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have u set this configuration parameter: dfs.namenode.acls.enabled = true

Comment: I had modified my post as few points were missed, Yes we have already set this parameter to true    dfs.namenode.acls.enabled = true

Comment: It looks like the default ACL is getting masked. Could you try changing the default fs.permissions.umask-mode? This could be an issue with hadoop.

Comment: [HDFS-6962](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962) looks like your problem. You will have to try your luck with this umask.

Comment: we tried changing that but even after that group write permission are not getting set , what we need is the acl permission (like 770 rwxrwx---) that we are setting for /sale/dir1 directory should be set for respective directory only ,  for other directory like /sale/dir2 it can be default permission . i am trying to figure out if i am missing any parameter setting to be changed for same to work in hadoop as group write permission are properly getting set for linux box without hadoop

Comment: The messages in the issue page linked in the previous comment also describe a very similar situation, of it working on linux and failing on HDFS.

Comment: Thanks Tavolo for the suggestion , it indeed is a hadoop bug for which solution is yet to be provided .

Comment: Since we cannot configure default permissions for any specific directory in HDFS due to known Hadoop HDFS Bug [ HDFS-6962 ] and changing dfs.umaskmode is a system wide setting. Is there a way we can change the umaskmode for individual users in Hadoop ?

Example: Any directory/file created by srv-test user would have a umask of 002 results if dir/file permissions of rwxrwxr-x.

Comment: Does [this](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/135gjtrg38/make-new-directories-writable-in-hdfs) help you?

Comment: this helps a bit , setting umask mode explicitly does help to provide different permission other than default umask set in property file while creating a new directory say test in hadoop , but if the newly permission set on test directory can be inherited by future incoming directories / files created under test directory then it would help solve my problem . Other way i was thinking if above scenario does not work out then whether it is possible to change umask for some users say bob and any directories / files created by bob user will have permission as per my requirement like 775 in hadoop